# MVC Unable to save data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**My application is modelled after NerdDinner presented in http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/.  I am having problem saving my posted edit and create pages even none of the business rules in the following Helper class is violated.  The only place that I can think of is the database table foreign keys are violated.  Could someone help me to catch the database exception?  Thanks.**

```
[Bind(Include = "TransfersID,AdmitDate,AdmitTime,MedDate,MedTime,Hospital,Ward,WardPhone," +
 "CaseMgrName,CaseMgrPhone,MDName,MDPhone,MDPager,AdmitDX,BedType,CallerName,CallerNumber," +
 "AcceptBy,ListStatus,StatusReport,FeePay,TXFRPriority,InfectionType,OffListReason,OffListDate," +
 "OffList,EnteredBy,VID,WardExtension,MDExtension,CaseMgrExtension,AddedToListDate," +
 "OffListTime,TxSource,TxReason,InpatientUnit,CBOC,CLC_ASIH,CNH,OtherServicesNA,BackToHomeFacility")]
public partial class Transfer
{

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
    {

        if (AdmitDate == null)
            yield return new RuleViolation("Admit date is required", "AdmitDate");

        if (Hospital == 0)
            yield return new RuleViolation("Hospital is required", "Hospital");

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AdmitDX))
            yield return new RuleViolation("Admit DX is required", "AdmitDX");

        if (BedType == 0)
            yield return new RuleViolation("Bed Type is required", "BedType");

        if (ListStatus == 0)
            yield return new RuleViolation("List Status is required", "ListStatus");

        yield break;
    }

    partial void OnValidate(ChangeAction action)
    {
        if (!IsValid)
            throw new ApplicationException("Rule violations prevent saving");
    }
}
```

**The controller has the following method.**

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Transfer collection)
    {
        Transfer transfer = vRepository.GetTransfer(id);

        if (transfer == null)
            return View("NotFound");
        else
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateModel<Transfer>(transfer);

                if (transfer.FeePay == 0) transfer.FeePay = null;
                if (transfer.InfectionType == 0) transfer.InfectionType = null;
                if (transfer.OffListReason == 0) transfer.OffListReason = null;
                if (transfer.TxSource == 0) transfer.TxSource = null;
                if (transfer.TxReason == 0) transfer.TxReason = null;
                if (transfer.OffListDate.HasValue) transfer.OffList = true;
                if (!transfer.OffListDate.HasValue) transfer.OffList = false;

                transfer.EnteredBy = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.EnteredBy);
                transfer.AdmitDX = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.AdmitDX);
                transfer.Ward = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.Ward);
                transfer.WardPhone = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.WardPhone);
                transfer.MDName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.MDName);
                transfer.MDPhone = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.MDPhone);
                transfer.MDPager = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.MDPager);
                transfer.CallerName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.CallerName);
                transfer.CallerNumber = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.CallerNumber);
                transfer.CaseMgrName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.CaseMgrName);
                transfer.CaseMgrPhone = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.CaseMgrPhone);
                transfer.TXFRPriority = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.TXFRPriority);
                transfer.AcceptBy = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.AcceptBy);
                transfer.StatusReport = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.StatusReport);
                transfer.CBOC = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.CBOC);
                transfer.CLC_ASIH = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.CLC_ASIH);
                transfer.CNH = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.CNH);
                transfer.OtherServicesNA = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(transfer.OtherServicesNA);
                transfer.EnteredBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

                vRepository.Save();

                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = transfer.TransfersID });
            }
            catch
            {
                ModelState.AddModelErrors(transfer.GetRuleViolations());

                return View(new TransferFormViewModel(transfer));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

****Both pages use shared form in a user controll.****

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<VS.Controllers.TransferFormViewModel>" %>
<% 
    var thisTransfer = Model.Transfer;
    var thisVS = thisTransfer.VS;
%>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Transfer for 
        <% 
        if (thisVS != null) 
               Response.Write(thisVS.FirstName + ' ' + thisVS.LastName);
        %>
        <%
        if (Model.Transfer.OffList.HasValue)
        {
            if ((bool)Model.Transfer.OffList)
                Response.Write(" (Off List)");
            else
                Response.Write(" (On List)");
        }
        %>
        </legend>
        <div class="sideBySideDiv">
        <p>
            <label for="TransferID">Transfer ID:</label>
            <%= thisTransfer.TransfersID %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="VID">VID:</label>
            <% if (thisVS!=null) Response.Write(thisVS.VID); %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="LastFourSSN">SSN:</label>
            <% if (thisVS!= null) Response.Write(thisVS.LastFourSSN);%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="DOB">DOB:</label>
            <% if (thisVS!= null) Response.Write(String.Format("{0:d}", thisVS.DOB));%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="_SC">%SC:</label>
            <% if (thisVS!= null) Response.Write(thisVS.PercentSC._SC);%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="PCP">PCP:</label>
            <% if (thisVS!=null) Response.Write(thisVS.PCP); %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Insurance">Insurance:</label>
            <% if (thisVS!= null) Response.Write(string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisVS.Insurance) ? "NA" : thisVS.Insurance); %>
        </p>  
        <p>
            <label for="COJ">COJ:</label>
            <% if (thisVS!= null) Response.Write(thisVS.Hospital.Hospital1); %>
        </p> 
        <p><label for="TransportElig">Eligibility:</label>
            <%if (thisVS!= null) Response.Write(thisVS.TransportElig ? "Yes" : "No"); %>
        </p> 
        <p>
            <label for="TxID">Transfer Record ID:</label>
            <%= thisTransfer.TransfersID %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("TxID", "*") %>
        </p>                                               
        <p>
            <label for="Hospital">Hospital:</label><br />
            <%= Html.DropDownList("Hospital", Model.CHospitals)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="AdmitDX">Admit DX:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("AdmitDX", thisTransfer.AdmitDX)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="BedType">Bed Type:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("BedType", Model.BedTypes)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="AdmitDate">Admit Date:</label>
            <%=Html.TextBox("AdmitDate", string.Format("{0:d}", thisTransfer.AdmitDate))%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="ListStatus">List Status</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("ListStatus", Model.StatusTypes)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Ward">Ward:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Ward", thisTransfer.Ward)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="WardPhone">Ward Phone</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("WardPhone", thisTransfer.WardPhone)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="MDName">Referred MD:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("MDName", thisTransfer.MDName)%>
       </p>
        <p>
            <label for="MDPhone">MD Phone:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("MDPhone", thisTransfer.MDPhone)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="MDPager">MD Pager:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("MDPager", thisTransfer.MDPager)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="AdmitTime">Admit Time:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("AdmitTime", string.Format("{0:t}",thisTransfer.AdmitTime))%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="CallerName">Caller Name:</label>
            <%=Html.TextBox("CallerName", thisTransfer.CallerName)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="CallerNumber">Caller Number:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("CallerNumber", thisTransfer.CallerNumber)%>
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sideBySideDiv">
        <p>
            <label for="CaseMgrName">Case Mgr:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("CaseMgrName", thisTransfer.CaseMgrName)%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="CaseMgrPhone">Mgr Phone:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("CaseMgrPhone", thisTransfer.CaseMgrPhone)%>
        </p>      
        <p>
            <label for="MedDate">Med Date:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("MedDate", string.Format("{0:d}",thisTransfer.MedDate))%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("MedDate", "*") %>
        </p> 
        <p>
            <label for="MedTime">Med Time:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("MedTime", string.Format("{0:t}",thisTransfer.MedTime))%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("MedTime", "*") %>
        </p>    
        <p>
            <label for="TXFRPriority">TXFR Priority:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("TXFRPriority", thisTransfer.TXFRPriority)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("TxPriority", "*") %>
        </p>  
        <p>
            <label for="AcceptBy">Accepted By:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("AcceptBy", thisTransfer.AcceptBy)%> 
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("AcceptBy", "*") %>
        </p> 
        <p>
            <label for="OffListReason">Off List Reason:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("OffListReason", Model.OffReasonTypes)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("OffListReason", "*") %>
        </p> 
        <p>
            <label for="OffListDate">Off List Date:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("OffListDate", string.Format("{0:d}", thisTransfer.OffListDate))%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("OffListDate", "*")%>
        </p>             
        <p>
            <label for="InfectionType">Infection Type:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("InfectionType", Model.InfectionTypes)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("InfectionType", "*") %>
        </p>                                                                     
        <p>
            <label for="FeePay">Fee Pay:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("FeePay", Model.FeePayReasons) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("FeePay", "*") %>
        </p> 
        <p>
            <label for="StatusReport">Status Report:</label>
            <%= Html.TextArea("StatusReport", thisTransfer.StatusReport)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("StatusReport", "*") %>
        </p>                                 
        </div>

        <div class="sideBySideDiv">
        <p>
            <label for="TxSource">Trnasfer Out Source:</label><br />
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxSource", "1", (thisTransfer.TxSource ?? 0) == 1 ? true : false, new { id = "TxSource_ED" })%>ED
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxSource", "2", (thisTransfer.TxSource ?? 0) == 2 ? true : false, new { id = "TxSource_EdPsych" })%>EdPsych
            <br />
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxSource", "3", (thisTransfer.TxSource ?? 0) == 3 ? true : false, new { id = "TxSource_InpatientUnit" })%>Inpatient Unit
            <%=Html.TextBox("InpatientUnit", thisTransfer.InpatientUnit)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("InpatientUnit", "*") %>
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxSource", "4", (thisTransfer.TxSource ?? 0) == 4 ? true : false, new { id = "TxSource_CBOC" })%>CBOC
            <%= Html.TextBox("CBOC", thisTransfer.CBOC)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("CBOC", "*") %>
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxSource", "5", (thisTransfer.TxSource ?? 0) == 5 ? true : false, new { id = "TxSource_CLC" })%>CLC
            <%= Html.TextBox("CLC_ASIH", thisTransfer.CLC_ASIH)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("CLC_ASIH", "*") %>
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxSource", "6", (thisTransfer.TxSource ?? 0) == 6 ? true : false, new { id = "TxSource_CNH" })%>CNH
            <%= Html.TextBox("CNH", thisTransfer.CNH)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("CNH", "*")%>

            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("TxOutSource", "*") %>
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
            <label for="TxReason">Treansfer Out Reason:</label><br />
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxReason", "1", (thisTransfer.TxReason ?? 0) == 1 ? true : false, new { id = "TxReason_EDdivert" })%>EDdivert
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxReason", "2", (thisTransfer.TxReason ?? 0) == 2 ? true : false, new { id = "TxReason_Trauma" })%>Trauma
            <br />
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxReason", "3", (thisTransfer.TxReason ?? 0) == 3 ? true : false, new { id = "TxReason_OBGYN" })%>OBGYN
            <br />
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxReason", "4", (thisTransfer.TxReason ?? 0) == 4 ? true : false, new { id = "TxReason_BedTypeNA" })%>Bed Type Not Available
            <br />
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxReason", "5", (thisTransfer.TxReason ?? 0) == 5 ? true : false, new { id = "TxReason_NonV" })%>Non V
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxReason", "6", (thisTransfer.TxReason ?? 0) == 6 ? true : false, new { id = "TxReason_NotEligible" })%>Not Eligible
            <br />
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxReason", "7", (thisTransfer.TxReason ?? 0) == 7 ? true : false, new { id = "TxReason_OtherServicesNotAvailable" })%>Other Services Not Available
            <%= Html.TextBox("OtherServiceNA", thisTransfer.OtherServicesNA)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("OtherServiceNA", "*") %>
            <%= Html.RadioButton("TxReason", "8", (thisTransfer.TxReason ?? 0) == 8 ? true : false, new { id = "TxReason_BackToHomeFacility" })%>Transfer Back to Home Facility
            <%= Html.TextBox("BackToHomeFacility",thisTransfer.BackToHomeFacility) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("BackToHomeFacility", "*") %>

            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("TxOutReason", "*") %>
        </p> 
         <p>
            <label for="AddedToListDate">Added to List Date:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("AddedToListDate", string.Format("{0:d}", thisTransfer.AddedToListDate))%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("AddedToListDate", "*")%>
        </p>           
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
<% } %><!-- close using Html.BeginForm()-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type, Transfer, of the collection parameter to your controller method seems wrong to me.  I'm thinking this data type should be a FormCollection since you are using the UpdateModel method to get the updates into your transfer object.

What I think is happening is that the form is being parsed and split into the Transfer class in the collection object.  This object is then ignored.  And because you don't have a FormCollection object in the method, the UpdateModel command doesn't do what it is supposed to.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I changed the collection parameter to FormCollection.  The catch block is executed.  I did another experiment by using the plain 

catch (Exception ex) 
{ View["Exception"] = ex.Message}

. It returns "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.". In the Edit view page, I add Response.Write(Request.Form) to inspect the form collection. All data in form is correct.  I also took the form data and cleaned the misc encoding and constructed a sql statement using the form data SQL Managemant Studio.  It succeeded.

Comment: By the way, it doesn't seem to matter that either using FormCollection or strong typed object, Transfer in this case.  They produce the same result.  I have another controller uses the strong type object as a parameter and works fine.